# Get browser history over 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, browser-history

[image: Android 6.0 changes]

Is there way to get history on Android 6.0 Marshmallow?

Answer (score 0):

This is intentionally not a supported use case. Using Android SDK's Browser provider right now it doesn't seems to provide history.

Look at this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200685

Answer (score 0):

API >= M ignores the permission argument and instead checks for com.android.chrome.permission.READ_WRITE_BOOKMARK_FOLDERS. This permission is **limited to system apps and apps signed with Google's key**.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Please refer to my answer as mention on below post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566687/7895502