# Read browser history in Marshmallow And Nougat Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-browser

I am trying to use Android Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI in Android Marshmallow. Until Lollipop, there is a way to read the history from the Chrome Browser using the permission. But in Marshmallow the permission is removed. Does any other alternative available for reading the browser history on a Marshmallow device?

I referred [This Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser), But not get a clear idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Web browsers were never obligated to use the `Browser` provider. And so, you have to do for Android 6.0+ what you really had to do for all prior versions of Android: contact the developers of each Web browser and ask them if they have an API for getting at this data.

Answer (score 3):

Due to security reason the browser history read/write are now not accessible by to the app. This step was taken by Google after `API >= 23`.

`query()` calls `hasReadAccess()`, which calls `hasPermission("com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS")`, which on `API >= M` ignores the permission argument and instead checks for **com.android.chrome.permission.READ_WRITE_BOOKMARK_FOLDERS**.
This permission is **limited to system apps and apps signed with Google's key.**

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Comment: Is this any other way for getting this?